# Android Room database giving SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException database disk image is malformed

Tags: android, android-room

I have tried to search for answers but could not find the solutions relevant to my case.
The case is
I have DAO class, and a method as

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun addInstrument(lastUsedInstrument: LastUsedInstrument)
```

by calling this method through database object as

```
database.lastUsedInstrumentDAO.addInstrument(lastInstrument)
```

I am **getting this exception in the implementation class of the DAO** interface.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException
database disk image is malformed (code 11 SQLITE_CORRUPT)

LastUsedInstrumentDAO_Impl.addInstrument (LastUsedInstrumentDAO_Impl.java:92)
```

Thanks

Comment: After deleting the database file (before deletion, make a backup) and recreating the database, do you get the Exception again?

Comment: not getting this crash frequently, observed very few crashes for live users.

Comment: Are you copying, moving or creating the database _file_ manually? If so, ensure that this file operation completes successfully.

Comment: not copying , but created an object. and just inserted the data into database.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this exception among a small number of users. I have a service in my app that writes data to the database every five seconds. The database structure contains a foreign key, I thought this was causing the problem, but according to your example this is not the case.

I assume that if the application process crashes (e.g. the phone is shut down due to low battery), then the data doesn't have time to be written to disk correctly, causing the database file to become corrupted.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a better way than to export important data to a json file periodically and in the onCreate method (Room.databaseBuilder(...).addCallback) check for a json file with data and restore it to the database. This method is called after automatically recreating the database file in the application.

The situation I am describing is taking place at Room 2.5.0-alpha02.